Como puedo ir cambiando en C# el "Source" de una Image creada con XAML
En XAML tengo estas imagenes, hay mas pero siguen el mismo patron.
        <!--Dibujamos los cuadrados que representan a todas las 16 opciones
                que tiene, los cuadrado estan por 2 mitades para poder
                ir marcando cuando aparece o desaparece la mitad de las 
                opciones, con el strech fill se consige que la imagen ocupe todo el espacio-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="ImagenesCuadrados"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:/Documentos Envi/Programas mios/Proyecto programador/Fondo verde.jpg"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:/Documentos Envi/Programas mios/Proyecto programador/Fondo verde.jpg"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:/Documentos Envi/Programas mios/Proyecto programador/Fondo verde.jpg"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:/Documentos Envi/Programas mios/Proyecto programador/Fondo verde.jpg"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>

Curiosamente he puesto el Source en XAML en algunas imagenes y me aparecen bien.
Pero cuando intento desde C# cambiar el Path del Source ya no aparecen y tampoco aparece la imagen indicada.
En C# tengo esta parte de programa para modificar el Image.Source.
        //Cuando se carga la Pagina se da el ancho de los cuadrados
        //  que representan las 16 opciones
        anchoMedioCuadrado = ((principal.ColumnaPrimeraLinea.Width.Value - 10) - (15 * 5)) / 32;

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        Uri uri = new Uri("C:/Documentos Envi/Programas mios/Proyecto programador/Fondo verde.jpg");
        bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;


        foreach (var item in ImagenesCuadrados.Children)
        {
            if(item is Image imagen)
            {
                imagen.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;

                imagen.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }

Tambien he intentado hacer un Binding pero tampoco lo he conseguido.
Poner directamente el Path tal como lo pongo en XAML tampoco funciona porque dice que no admite String.

Debes crear un BitmapImage pasando por parametro el URI
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"carpetas\imagen.png"));
imagen.Source = bmi;


Esta forma es mas reducida y funciona correctamente, aunque no entiendo porque cuando yo la probé separando el URI no funcionaba aparte de poner @ delante del string conteniendo el path

Gracias a vosotros voy avanzando en esto de la programacion

@FamiliaParra Porque tu usaste la propiedad UriSource el cual obliga a usar en conjunto las funciones BeginInit y EndInit, en cambio cuando lo pasas directo al constructor no es necesario, ya que en el constructor se llaman esas funciones automáticamente.

Comprendo, he mirado y he visto que hay un constructor(Uri), gracias, me siento un ... sin palabras y no se que quiero consegir con mis ideas de hacer algo con tanta ignorancia

@FamiliaParra Este tipo de cosas son demasiado específicas, uno no se entera que existen hasta que surge el problema. Al igual que tú, yo también batallé con este tema, así que creo que es lo normal

Proba de la siguiente forma:
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = new Uri(ImageSource);
image.EndInit();
ImageControl.Source = image;

Esto deberia funcionarte...

ImageSource me aparece un error diciendo "es tipo, que no es valida en el contexto indicado".

ImageControl.Source tambien me dá error diciendo "no existe en el contexto actual" y la he probado de poner dentro del foreach y tampoco me lo permite

Donde pone "ImageSource" he puesto el Path y me lo ha aceptado pero he tenido que quitar el "ImageControl.Source" y lo pruebo pero no aparecen

Perdon, anulando "ImageControl.Source" han aparecido las imagenes.

Gracias, no entiendo muy bien lo que hemos hecho pero me lo estudiaré para comprenderlo.
